# Issue in passing relative url of images for optimisation

Tags: php, image, magento

I am working on magento 1.9 installation. I need to optimize images before/at the time of page loading.
I have refered so many php scripts for this,
http://zenverse.net/php-reducing-image-filesize-using-gd/ - I found this much better option. But it cannot create image from the image url.
The error log says:

```
ERR (3): Warning: imagejpeg(): Unable to open 'http://mydomain/media/catalog/product/cache/3/small_image/180x180/9df785d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/4/8461c5c67fab50b68781772a4df.jpg' for writing: No such file or directory.
```

The function compress_image($source_url, $destination_url, $quality) works properly for local images. I searched on net for the issue,  it says I need to pass relative url. I tried so many times but noting worked.
My code in list.phtml:

```
<?php /* Display optimised images */
    $img = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($imgX, $imgY);
    $imgsrc = Mage::helper('featured')->compress_image($img, $img, 90);
    ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $imgsrc; ?> " width="<?php echo $imgX; ?>" height="  <?php echo $imgY; ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>"/>
```

I dont know what I am missing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: just <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($imgX, $imgY); ?>

Comment: But Google Page Speed Insights still ask to optimize the image.

Comment: for google you can set height and width not need to compress it.

Comment: could you post the value of $imgsrc and directory for your image files? It could be that you need to move compressed files from  $imgsrc to image directory

Comment: The function called is:

 public function compress_image($source_url, $destination_url, $quality)
 {  
  $info = getimagesize($source_url);
  if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg')
  {
   $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_url);
   imagejpeg($image, $destination_url, $quality);
  }
  elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png')
  {
   $image = imagecreatefrompng($source_url); 
   imagepng($image, $destination_url, $quality);
  }
  
  //return destination file url
  return $destination_url;
 }
 
 
 But the line :$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_url); causes error.

Comment: ok, and what is $source_url ? Am I right it is $img variable in compress_image($img, $img, 90) invocation ?

Comment: I would recommend you to read this post as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711253/how-to-resize-the-categories-images-in-magento

Comment: @sr3z: Yes. Its the $img variable passed to the function.